# when i add the form tag page design changes a lot

Tags: html, css

i bought a web site template. (html5, boostrap). I need a dynamic web site so i am gonna change these html pages to the asp.net pages. so i need a form tag after body tag. i have already added this but page design changes a lot (looks not good) when i add a form tag after body tag. how can i fix this problem? i think, i need to add some style properties to this new form tag. but i tried lots of things. they didnt work.

Here is the link of original page: (without a form tag)

http://www.gundem90.com/original/index.html
also there is a another index page. index2.html

and here is the link after i add a form tag:

http://www.gundem90.com/withformtag/index.html
also there is a another index page. index2.html

thanks.

Comment: I cant see any design changes (in firefox and chrome), and why are you trying to add the form tag after body tag???

Comment: you can see page design changes if you click search button. i need a form tag covers all page for asp.net. so i need to add this form tag after body tag. thanks!!

Comment: There is a `form` element in the original already, for the search functionality – so you can not just put another form around the whole body content, since nesting forms is not allowed in HTML. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.gundem90.com/withformtag/index.html

Comment: _“i need a form tag covers all page for asp.net”_ – that makes little sense, resp. is way to broad. You should specify first, what exactly you need form functionality for on this page – and then place it in an appropriate location. (That might involve learning some more HTML basics beforehand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the issue is because of the missing class `"navbar-form"`, try to update your class "input-group" with the below, or else just wrap the `input-group` with a form tag with the class `navbar-form`!! hope this will fix your issue!!

**CSS**

```
.input-group {
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 15px !important;
    width: 500px;
}
```

**include the below styles to your stylesheet**

```
.input-group input.form-control{
    width:85%;
}
.input-group .input-group-btn{
    float:left;
}
```

**for mobile screen**

just remove the `width:500px` from the class `.input-group`

Comment: hello. i have implemented your input-group css. i removed current one. but it didnt work. search box is still so big. can you check this NEW link. gundem90.com/latest/index.html and index2.html

Comment: have u really included the above mentioned css "input-group"??, since I cant able to find the class over there, I can the class only in the style sheet (bootstrap.min.css), not in your stylesheet (style.default.css)

Comment: i changed boostrap.css. i did not change style.default.css. Now i have fixed boostrap.css BACK. and i have changed your css solution at boostrap.min.css. I think it did not work. if anyway i can share you files. s.selcuk@hotmail.com

Comment: still I cant able to see d update. Ok, try to include the above style to your stylesheet and let me know!

Comment: i checked your code.. it is in the file. (boostrap.min.css)

Comment: .input-group{float: right; padding: 30px 15px !important; width: 500px;}.btn-toolbar>.btn,.btn-toolbar>.btn-group,.btn-toolbar>.input-group{margin-left:5px}.btn-group>.btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle){border-radius:0}

Comment: if it is okay for you i can send you these pages via email. i just need you to send me an email.

Comment: you've included the css under ".btn-toolbar .input-group", this is not correct, just add it separately as I shown above or else just paste the above css in your default stylesheet, thats what I already told you.

Comment: okay i did it. it changed. it is better. but now search button goes down little bit lol. thanks

Comment: index.html and index2.html same problem. (search button goes down little bit)

Comment: dear aru, is there any solution for this button also? thanks. ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, update your stylesheet with that to get this fixed!!